# SQL statement to get column based on ID from same table

Tags: sql, key

The table is like so:

| ID | Name | SupervisorID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | NULL |
| 2 | Michael | NULL |
| 3 | David | 1 |

SupervisorID is a foreign key of ID. So, David's SupervisorID of 1 refers to John.

I want to write a statement that retrieves just Name and Supervisor Name, where applicable. So the result-set should look like this:

| Name | Supervisor |
| --- | --- |
| John | NULL |
| Michael | NULL |
| David | John |

It seems like it should be simple but I can't work it out.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: self LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I'm having problems still: "Subquery returns more than 1 row". Could I get another hint please?

Comment: No need for a subquery, just LEFT JOIN the table with itself.

Comment: I've had a go testing a statement, but there are 6 million records in the table, and it's taking forever to execute. So I can't test whether I'm doing the correct thing.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ is handy in such cases. You can even set up a test case (creating table and inserting data), and add the link to it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do a *self* `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2 on t2.ID = t1.SupervisorID
```

(Doing a LEFT JOIN to also return people without a supervisor.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
select  Name, Name as superior from tablename where tablename.ID==tablename.superiorID
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only returns records where a person's Supervisor ID is the same as their own ID. So it returns 0 records.

Comment: Tip: you can go to https://dbfiddle.uk to verify your SQL.